# Empty array after pushing to another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to push array A to B inside cycle and then and for every iteration of B i need to delete array A and create new one. I get all data before clearing the array, but after clearing I get array B with empty values

Code :

```
for (i = 0; i < XArray.length; i++) {
    var pointsArray = [];

    for (j = 0; j < XArray.length; j++) {

        if (XArray[i] == XArray[j]) {
            pointsArray.push([parseFloat(YArray[i]), parseFloat(ZArray[i])]);
        }
    }

    dataSource.push({
        name: i,
        data: pointsArray
    });
    pointsArray.length = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The last line

```
pointsArray.length = 0;
```

removes every element in the array you created in the first line. And since all objects are assigned by reference (and arrays are objects), the `data` property of the object will now point to an empty array. Here is a simplified example:

```
var a = [1, 2];
var b = a;
a.length = 0;
console.log(b); // [] -- an empty array
```

So, your current code has the same effect as

```
dataSource.push({
    name: i,
    data: []
});
```

**Solution:** Just *remove the last line* and it will work as expected.

Comment: pointsCopy = pointsArray.slice();
                        dataSource.push({name: i, data: pointsCopy});                        
                        pointsArray.length = 0;

Comment: @incredible_titan: I'm not sure what you mean. But you can see here in this simplified example that in, http://jsfiddle.net/AsTzK, you end up with empty arrays whereas if the line's removed, you don't: http://jsfiddle.net/AsTzK/1/. If this solution doesn't work for you, then there must be something different in your code.

Comment: @FelixKling For example : I have source array with names of countries and other array with products. Indicies of  both arrays are equal. <br/> array1:{China, China, Korea, USA, USA}, array2:{Lenovo, Asus, Samsung, Apple, Blackberry}, result : array : {{China, {Lenovo, Asus}} ...}

Comment: @incredible_titan: I understand your code. I didn't understand what you mean by *"has the same result as result without zeroing pointsArray"*. Does this mean it works for your or not?

Comment: @FelixKling. No, it doesn't. It always gives result : {{China, Lenovo}, {China, Asus} ...}. I mean that array contains not separated values

Comment: @incredible_titan: So it's not empty anymore, which was what the question was about. That the data is not grouped correctly seems to be a different, new problem.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for your advice. You realy open my eyes to assigning objects as references. And today I had found the solution of my problem :).